# Как вставить кавычку в переменную?

Tags: golang

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var (
        a string
    )
    fmt.Fscan(os.Stdin, &a)

    fmt.Println("I wanna some ,", a)

}
```

Чтобы получился результат:

```
I wanna some 'перемененная'
```

Answer (score 3):

Если устраивают двойные:

```golang
fmt.Printf("I wanna some %q", a)
```

Если нужны единичные, то можно так:

```golang
fmt.Printf("I wanna some '%s'", a)
```

Но тут могут быть проблемы с экранированием.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте пожалуйста

```
fmt.Println("I wanna some '" +a+"'")
```

Comment: Нет, между кавычками пробелы не нужны.

Comment: А так попробуйте

Comment: I wanna some ' 1 ' снова пробелы. Должно вот так I wanna some, '1'   =(

Comment: Да откуда берутся они? А вводите вы 1? Или с пробелом

Comment: fmt.Println("I wanna some, '" + a) решил

Comment: Автор, у тебя глюки - все способы, которые тебе предложили - рабочие. А твой способ это какой-то маразм. Потому что он создает строку со значением без закрывающей кавычки: I wanna some, '1